# azure blob python library - hanging on readinto() function

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have been struggling with an application hang, randomly, I have a very large number of files to download (~100k), after a random number the script will hang, and not exit with any useful errors.

This is my code to download a blob:

```
        with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
            logger.info("Downloading to " + file_name+" ...")
            blob_client.download_blob().readinto(file)
```

I tried limiting the script to 1000 files at a time, but after a few runs it will eventually lock again. Without the application hanging or providing any error information, all our attempts to resolve the issue have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid Application hang while using `readinto()` function, please try below:**

- Try setting **`max_concurrency`** which increases the speed of blob download like below:

```py
blob_client.download_blob(max_concurrency=10).readinto(download_file)
```

You can try changing **`max_concurrency`** value to get better results.

- If the above doesn't work, make use of below **[script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10572#issuecomment-745232190)** if helpful:

```
 blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_str, container_name=container, blob_name=blob)
 download_stream = blob.download_blob(max_concurrency=DOWNLOAD_FILE)
      with open(target_path, 'Your_Path') as target_file:
        download_stream.readinto(target_file)
```

- **Otherwise**, try setting **`read_timeout="a large number in second"`** while initiating BlobClient like below:

```
.BlobClient(account_url, container_name, blob_name, credential, read_timeout=8000)
```

You can **refer** the below link for more information:

[VERY slow large blob downloads · Issue #10572 · Azure/azure-sdk-for-python · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10572)

Comment: We have tried these options, but still faces application hang. Ultimately we stopped using the library.